# Problem with using footnotes in xepersian

Tags: errors, footnotes, xepersian, persian

I have a quite long document that I compile with no errors.(I got rid of most of warnings but a few of them relating to defined fonts remained!) As I try to add footnotes to my documents, it gives some warnings/errors that I found no information about it online. I am sure the problem is caused by adding footnotes.

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
  \usepackage{xepersian}
 \usepackage{pifont}
 \settextfont[Scale=1.2]{B Nazanin}
 \defpersianfont\nastaliq[Scale=2]{IranNastaliq}
 \defpersianfont\titr[Scale=1]{B Titr}
 \defpersianfont\traffic[Scale=1]{B Traffic}
 \deflatinfont\calibri{Calibri}    
 \begin{document}

\chapter{}
\section{نمونه‌برداری فشرده}

نمونه‌برداری مشاهده \footnote{\lr{\calibri{dimension reduction}}} می‌باشد فشرده یک زمینه‌ی تحقیقاتی به سرعت در حال توسعه است که توجه بسیاری را در رشته‌های مهندسی برق، ریاضیات کاربردی، آمار و علوم کامپیوتر به خود جلب کرده است.

\end{document}
```

What consule output displays:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/BNazanin(0)/bx/n' undefined
(Font)              using `EU1/BNazanin(0)/m/n' instead on input line 14.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `footdir@1' on page 1 undefined on input line 17.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `footdir@2' on page 1 undefined on input line 17.

! You can't use `\relax' after \the.
<recently read> \c@zabspage 

l.19     \end{document}

?
```

Added `\usepcakge{footnote}` but the problem persists.

Comment: Well if you are certain that footnotes are the problem then you should be able to shorten your document considerably.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of doing that. Will do it in a minute or so @UlrikeFischer

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I am not sure if what I removed won't cause errors if someone tries to run it but I made the MWE much shorter anyway.

Comment: It's still very long: are all packages needed? Delete the unnecessary ones. Is the title formatting relevant? I think they're not. :P And so on. Also, delete the space between one package and the other.

Comment: @Alenanno: Done!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is due to the new version of `zref-abspage`, which breaks the `bidi` package.
Try `\usepackage[extrafootnotefeatures]{xepersian}` instead of `\usepackage{xepersian}` and it should not give you the error anymore.

BTW, for left-ro-right footnotes, you can use `\LTRfootnote`. Like this:

```
\LTRfootnote{dimension reduction}
```

Also you can use `\setlatintextfont` to set latin font for your whole document. Like this:

```
\setlatintextfont{Calibri}
```

This means that this font will be used whenever you use `\lr` or other commands that change the environment to latin (left-to-right).

Comment: Thank you very much, I was in need of a solution like this.